# LinkedHashMap - contains method

Tags: java, contains, linkedhashmap

I need to read a flag to validate if I'll send or not an email, this flag is on a `LinkedHashMap`, so I'm trying to go over it looking for an ID, then I'll have to ask if is true or false, and I'm trying this:

```
    while(iterator.hasNext()){

         LinkedHashMap<String, Object> fileMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) iterator.next();
         userid = (Long)fileMap.get("USERID");
         file.findAllFiles(userid);

         if(file.findAllFiles(userid).contains(haveFiles = true)){
             //send email
         }else{
             //do something
         }

     }
```

Is it correct?

Comment: have you tried the code? does it give you any error?

Comment: my guess is your userID is type object? what does findAllFiles do?

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: findAllFiles is a method who needs a Long, (that's the reason that i used a cast) findAll returns a map extract from a db, with a lot of values but i'm only interesting in one: haveFiles flag.

Comment: yes!! no errors, it compile :S

Comment: Did you declare a "haveFiles" local variable (or field) anywhere? I am trying to compile that in my head.

Comment: @rpassenger you should give us something that we can reproduced in our computers in order to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your if expression has a logical error.

```
haveFiles = true
```

will always return true, reducing your expression to :

```
file.findAllFiles(userid).contains(true)
```

since `(haveFiles = true)` assigns the value true to the variable haveFiles.

You should rather be doing something on the following lines :

```
Map<Flag, Boolean> keyValueMap = file.findAllFiles(userid)
if(keyValueMap.contains(Flag.HAVE_FILES) == true){
     //send email
 }else{
     //do something
 }
```

..asuming you the file.findAllFiles() returns a map object with flags and their boolean status and Flag is an enum containing all the supported flags.

The expression

```
(keyValueMap.contains(Flag.HAVE_FILES) == true)
```

will evaluate to true only when keyValueMap contains an entry for Flag.HAVE_FILES and the value is true.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it works up to the point of:

```
if(file.findAllFiles(userid).contains(haveFiles = true))
```

Then I think the issue is in that condition itself. What you have written is roughly equivalent of writing

```
??? haveFiles = true;    
if(file.findAllFiles(userid).contains(haveFiles))
```

(where ??? can be either `Object`, `Boolean` or `boolean`, don't know from your code snapshot)

I bet what you might want to do is something like

```
Boolean haveFiles = file.findAllFiles(userid).get("haveFiles");
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(haveFiles) {
```

What you have done calls the `contains` method which receives any Object and returns true if that object is among the values of the map. You probably don't want that, I guess what you want to do is to retrieve the value associated to the "haveFiles" key into the map, for that you have to use the `get` method.

PS: Also, if `file.findAllFiles(userid)` method is truly calling some DB stuff you might want to invoke it only once (the first time looks totally unnecesary to me).